# Understanding this Jquery error

Tags: jquery, json

Failing miserably here trying to get this jquery to work within my app, not quite understanding the errors and some of the flow of the functions. I think that maybe i am not referencing the correct objects through some of the functions. The goal here is to grab 5 tweets from my twitter feed and then only show 1 at a time in a loop.

```
var $container = $('#innerTwitter');
$.get('/feed', function (data) {
    $container.empty();
    $(data).slice(0, 5).each(function (_, tweet) {
        var $tweet = $(document.createElement('p'));
        $tweet.text(tweet.text);
        $container.append($tweet);
    });
}, 'json');

function showTweets(tweets) {
    var tweetPs = $.map(tweets, function (t) {
        return $('<p></p>').text(t.text).hide();
    });
    container.append(tweetPs);
    tweetPs[0].show();
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var nextTweet = function () {
        var nextIndex = currentIndex == tweets.length - 1 ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
        tweetPs[currentIndex].fadeOut(400, function () {
            tweetPs[nextIndex].fadeIn(400);
        });
        currentIndex = nextIndex;
    };
    setInterval(nextTweet, 2000);
}
showTweets(tweets);
```

My error is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Just a guess. Shouldn't `tweets.length` be `tweetsPs.length`? A typo perhaps.

Comment: hmm, ok so amended that, good spot, now all 5 tweets show at the same time with no loop?

Comment: You are calling `showTweets` without passing an argument. Hence `tweets` will be `undefined` inside `showTweets` and `$.map(tweets, ...)` will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

showTweets() function expects a parameter 'tweets' which you are not passing.

Comment: ok added that, still the same, all 5 tweets showing with no loop and error tweets is not defined

Comment: @Richlewis: Well, in `showTweets(tweets);` you are now trying to pass the variable `tweets` to the function. If the variable is not defined you will get an error. You defined `showTweets` such that it expects an array of tweets. This array does not come out of nowhere, you have to create it.

Comment: What is the response from Twitter? You may be receiving an error that's why you are not able to display your tweets.